# VB NET Manage dynamic components functions

Tags: vb.net

I have to create dynamic tabs. In these tabs I create other components like TextBoxes, Buttons and DataGridViews...

```
//...Create New Component
AddHandler NewButton.Click, AddressOf Function

Private Sub Function(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
//Code
End Sub
```

How can I manage a component created dynamically?
I want to search a value into the new DataGridView.

1. Create New DataGridView
2. Create New Textbox
3. Create New Button
4. When Button is pressed search Textbox value in DataGridView and return RowIndex

Answer (score 0):

`Control.name = "SpecificName"`

will be your best friend

What I normally do is set the names to be something like `"tabXdgvX"` or `"tabXtbX"`

where `tabX` is tab number like tab1 or tab2

and `dgvX` or `tbX` is the GridView or TextBox number.

Then it's easy to quickly find and identify tabs and controls regardless of how many are on each one.

Just use for statements and nested for statements to search and manipulate.

Just make sure that when you create the controls, you have some sort of rhyme or reason to it to make programmatically calling them easier.